# What is the meaning of "yea, marie"?

Tags: idioms, early-modern-english

The preface to John Calvin's [*Sermons on Deuteronomy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ftnYAAAAMAAJ&q=%22Yea+marie:+but+that+should+haue%22&dq=%22Yea+marie:+but+that+should+haue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjImPHxl6PUAhVK-2MKHfw6DwwQ6AEIJDAA) says this:

> For sufficient proofe whereof, and to the end it should not be thought that we do wrongfully & without cause giue inkling of the things afore said: we will briefly touch what hath bin doone herein a fewe yeares since: namely that there haue bin certaine men, who without any forecast, haue bin so bolde as to cause certain sermons vpon the Prophet Danyel to be printed, without vouchsafing to see the originall copie, or to be aduertised there of from hence. And to couer their whole doings the better, they alledge that their so doing was for the glorie of God. **Yea marie**: but that should haue beene done without the hinderance of other men.

I think I still have not understood clearly the meaning of this expression. Some say it is an expression of surprise, but I still couldn't get its meaning.

Also, it would be good to have some modern expressions with the same meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Marry](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/marry) was "an archaic exclamation of surprise, anger. etc"; there is not enough context to say whether a latter-day Calvin would say "Yeah, right", "Well, maybe" or something else entirely.

Comment: So, its meaning can be something with a sarcastic touch?

Comment: Possibly ironic, probably not sarcastic. This is getting beyond language and into literary criticism: how many different shades of meaning does *right* have as an interjection?